# AspectJ 1.9.4 with OpenJDK 11 Without Spring Context not working as a dependent module

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to create custom loadtime annotations with AspectJ, Open JDK11 without Spring Context. It works fine within a module and annotations are weaving at class load time and aspects are executing at runtime. No issues, But when aspectJ implemented module added as a dependency on another module. AspectJ and annotations are not processing. Am I missing any configuration?

**module-a**

```java
@Documented
@Inherited
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Counter {
    String name() default "";
}
```

```java
@Aspect
public class CounterAspect {
    @Around("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(counter)")
    public void myBeforeLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Counter counter) {

        System.out.println("Okay - we're in the before handler...");
        System.out.println("The test annotation value is: " + counter.name().toString());
}
```

**resources/META-INF/aop.xml**

```xml
<aspectj>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="CounterAspect"/>
    </aspects>
    <weaver options="-verbose">
        <!-- weave anything -->
        <include within="*" />
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**module-b**

**pom.xml**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mymodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-a</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
public class MyCounter {
    @Counter(name="call_count")
    public void count() {}
}
```

```java
public class MyCounterTest {
    @Test
    public void testCount() {
        MyCounter counter = new MyCounter();
        counter.count();
        //NOTE: I expect CounterAspect from module-a should be intercepted. It is not working!!!! There is no aspectJ class loading verbose in console.
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked  module-b's dependency? Does it inlclude AspectJ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added and tested still my aspects are not getting called. Updated pom.xml on module-b.

Comment: It does not help you to define Surefire running with a load-time weaver on the first module if your test is in the second one. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a parent POM with some predefined properties, dependency versions and plugin configurations. Your two sub-modules (one for application + test, one for aspect) can use these definitions, which leads to shorter sub-module POMs:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-ltw-test-multi-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.source-target.version>11</java.source-target.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
            <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
            <!-- IMPORTANT -->
            <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
          <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.12.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <!--<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>-->
            <source>${java.source-target.version}</source>
            <target>${java.source-target.version}</target>
            <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
            <complianceLevel>${java.source-target.version}</complianceLevel>
            <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
            <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
            <!--<warn>constructorName,packageDefaultMethod,deprecation,maskedCatchBlocks,unusedLocals,unusedArguments,unusedImport</warn>-->
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <!-- IMPORTANT -->
              <phase>process-sources</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
              <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
              <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.9</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspect</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <modules>
    <module>aspect</module>
    <module>application</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Please note that I am not using the original AspectJ Maven plugin but a fork which supports Java 11. The original still lags behind. As you said you want to use Java 11, you have to do that. With Java 8 you can use the original plugin.

**Aspect module:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-ltw-test-multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspect</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

```xml
<aspectj>
  <aspects>
    <aspect name="de.scrum_master.aspect.CounterAspect"/>
  </aspects>
  <weaver options="-verbose">
    <!-- weave anything -->
    <include within="*"/>
  </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Documented
@Inherited
@Target(METHOD)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Counter {
  String name() default "";
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

@Aspect
public class CounterAspect {
  @Around("execution(* *.*(..)) && @annotation(counter)")
  public void myBeforeLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Counter counter) {
    System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> " + counter.name());
  }
}
```

**Application module:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-ltw-test-multi-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
  <artifactId>application</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>de.scrum-master</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>
            -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
          </argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import de.scrum_master.aspect.Counter;

public class MyCounter {
  @Counter(name = "call_count")
  public void count() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MyCounterTest {
  @Test
  public void testCount() {
    new MyCounter().count();
  }
}
```

Now if you run `mvn clean verify` or just `mvn clean test` you will get the following console log for the application module test:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.4 built on Friday May 10, 2019 at 08:43:10 PDT
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info register classloader jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@2aae9190
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info using configuration (...)/SO_AJ_LTWTestMultiModule_56397605/aspect/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info register aspect de.scrum_master.aspect.CounterAspect
[IsolatedClassLoader@74e52ef6] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.9.4 built on Friday May 10, 2019 at 08:43:10 PDT
[IsolatedClassLoader@74e52ef6] info register classloader org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.IsolatedClassLoader@74e52ef6
[IsolatedClassLoader@74e52ef6] info using configuration (...)/SO_AJ_LTWTestMultiModule_56397605/aspect/target/classes/META-INF/aop.xml
[IsolatedClassLoader@74e52ef6] info register aspect de.scrum_master.aspect.CounterAspect
Running de.scrum_master.app.MyCounterTest
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access using Lookup on org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor (file:/(...)/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.4/aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar) to class java.lang.ClassLoader
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassLoaderWeavingAdaptor
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info processing reweavable type de.scrum_master.aspect.CounterAspect: de\scrum_master\aspect\CounterAspect.aj
[AppClassLoader@2aae9190] info successfully verified type de.scrum_master.aspect.CounterAspect exists.  Originates from de\scrum_master\aspect\CounterAspect.aj
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyCounter.count()) -> call_count
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.885 sec
```

Please especially note

```
execution(void de.scrum_master.app.MyCounter.count()) -> call_count
```

This is what you want, the load-time-woven aspect kicks in for your test.

---

**Update:** I created a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kriegaex/SO_AJ_LTWTestMultiModule_56397605) for you. You can just clone it instead of copying all my code snippets from this answer.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex. It worked. Very much appreciated for your directions.

Comment: It is working fine for Junits. If i create spark endpoint and call those methods doesnt process annotations. How do I attach Java agent at runtime process.

Comment: You attach the Java agent via command line, just like you do for the test. Or use compile-time weaving instead of load-time. There is also an option to attach it via Java code, but it will only work for classes loaded after you attached the weaving agent and somehow the point of AOP is that the application doesn't need to know about cross-cutting concerns, so why would you activate it from within that application? Anyway, this is a new question, not something for a comment. Please open a new question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as usual on SO.